# How to Estimate Covariance Matrix using Wishart Distribution?

Tags: estimation, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, wishart-distribution

I learned that Wishart distribution can help estimate covariance matrix of MVN without sampling directly from MVN. But there are some points that are still unclear for me:

1. Why we bother to estimate covariance, while we have a sample covariance unbiased estimator for MVN?
2. For using Wishart distribution to estimate the covariance, I assume we still need the variance of all the variables or correlations. How should we plug them into Wishart formula? Can we use the sample variance of the variables?
3. Does Wishart estimation work for any different values of means in MVN?
4. Is there any other way available (harder or simpler) to estimate the covariance matrix from unknown distribution?

Your responses would be appreciated.